# Is 'insert tokens' broken for TinyMCE when creating templates

Tags: tokens, message-templates, wysiwyg, tinymce

Have shown this to be the case on 2 sites. First site reported the problem and were using TinyMCE. Second site was using CKEditor had no such problem. I then set their wysiwyg to TinyMCE and bingo replicated problem. Can't replicate on Demo as demo user is missing permissions to edit Message Templates.

My search on [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15278) found this which may be an earlier example of the problem, but perhaps it has come back to life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it was a bug. Here's a fix for 4.7.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7438

The code in 4.7 is a lot cleaner than 4.6; I don't think fixing it in 4.6 will be a priority for the core team.